# Arithmetic Expressions in Python not working with more than one place value

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

This is a parser I'm trying to create, and it's going well, but somehow I can't do arithmetic expressions with more than one place value. It works for everything up to 9 but nothing like 10 or 21. The second function is just for integrating accessing text files.

For example, I can do `9 * 9` , but I cannot do `12 * 8`.

```
# AditPradipta_Equation_Solving

def only_parsing(equation):
    operators = {0: lambda x, y : int(x) + int(y),
         1: lambda x, y : int(x) - int(y),
         2: lambda x, y : int(x) * int(y),
         3: lambda x, y : int(x) / int(y)}
    operators_list = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    equation = equation.strip()
    equation = equation.strip("=")
    print(equation)
    operator_num = 0
    for operator in operators_list:
        if operator_num == 3:
            zero_division_check = equation.find("0")
            if not zero_division_check != True:
                continue
            elif not zero_division_check != False:
                return "You cannot divide by 0."
        operator_find = equation.find(operators_list[operator_num])
        if not operator_find != True:
            first_num = equation[0]
            second_num = equation[-1]
            return operators[operator_num](int(first_num), int(second_num))
        else:
           operator_num = operator_num + 1

def multi_line_parsing(filename, new_file_name):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    file_lines = file.readlines()
    print(file_lines)
    new_file = []
    for line in file_lines:
        print(line)
        new_file.append(str(only_parsing(line)) + str("\n"))
        print(new_file)
    new_file_string_data = ''.join(new_file)
    print(new_file_string_data)
    file.close()
    write_file = open(new_file_name, 'w+')
    write_file.write(new_file_string_data)
    write_file.close()
    return

file_name = input("Please enter a filename: ")
new_file = input("Please enter another new file name: ")
multi_line_parsing(file_name, new_file)
```

An example of expected input and output and actual input and output is

```
    #Expected input
    12 * 8
    100 * 10

    #Expected Output
    96
    1000

    #Actual Output
    None
    None
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give 2 lines of sample text ? Withe current output, and the expected output please.

Comment: done :) Thanks I'll try and put sample's in from the start now

Comment: 12*8 is not 64 and 100*10 is not 10. There are a couple of issues with your code. But the one that jumps to my face here is, you take the first char of the string and the last for the both numbers. This way you always get only one digit of a number that actually got two. Maybe parse your equation by regex if its simple like that.

Comment: There are some issues you need to clarify -  
  
1. `.find` returns `-1` if not found and you are comparing that to `True` or `False` which will always be `False`  
  
2. You need to add the intent of your code, what do you wish to achieve?  
  
3. Even if `.find` returns a boolean, the way you are checking boolean is really strange. Instead of `if not zero_division_check != True`, simply write `if not zero_division_check`

Comment: your error lies in these 2 lines `first_num = equation[0]` ,`second_num = equation[-1]` since equation is a string you are basically asking for the first character and last in `12 * 8` you are getting `1` and `8` this is why single digits work.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong inputs I did that absentmindedly but thx thats works now.

Comment: @layog: You flipped the logic; `if not zero_division_check != True:` is (for boolean inputs) equivalent to `if zero_division_check:`, no `not` involved. For non-booleans, the more complicated check is mostly nonsensical, as you note.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: `str.split()` ... good only ... formatted with delimiting spaces.
>     It won't correctly tokenize **"12*8"**

To handle both, and other possible format, replace with `re.split(...)`, for example:

```
    import re
    # Split by blank, require ALWAYS three parts delimited with blank
    v1, v2 = re.split('[\+\-\*\/]', equation)
    op = equation[len(v1)]
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> 12*8 = 96  
> 12* 8 = 96  
> 100  *10 = 1000  
> division by zero: You cannot divide by 0  
> 12 / 0 = None
> ```

---

> **Question**: Arithmetic Expressions ... not working with more than one place value

Using `str.split()` you can handle Values of any length.

Simplify your approach, for example:

```
def only_parsing(equation):
    # Use the operators as dict key
    operators = {'+': lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y),
                 '-': lambda x, y: int(x) - int(y),
                 '*': lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y),
                 '/': lambda x, y: int(x) / int(y)}

    # Split by blank, require ALWAYS three parts delimited with blank
    v1, op, v2 = equation.split()
    #print("{}".format((v1, op, v2)))

    # Use try:...except to catch ZeroDivisionError
    try:
        # Call the lambda given by dict key
        return operators[op](v1, v2)

    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("{}: You cannot divide by 0".format(e,))

for exp in ['12 * 8', '100 * 10', '12 / 0']:
    print("{} = {}".format(exp, only_parsing(exp)))
```

> **Qutput**:
>
> ```
> 12 * 8 = 96  
> 100 * 10 = 1000  
> division by zero: You cannot divide by 0  
> 12 / 0 = None
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: `str.split()` is good only as long as input data is formatted with delimiting spaces. It won't correctly tokenize "12*8", though this is certainly valid-looking.